# Show identity $\sum_{k=0}^{n-s}(\Delta^sq_k)^2=(KQ)^TKQ$.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, optimization

> Show the identity
>
> $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-s}(\Delta^sq_k)^2=(KQ)^TKQ$$

where

$$Q=(q_0,\ldots,q_n)^T$$

$$\Delta^sq_k=\sum_{v=0}^{s}(-1)^v\binom{s}{v}q_{k+v}$$

$$K=(K_{ij})_{0\leq i \leq n-s,\  0 \leq j \leq n}$$ with

$$K_{ij}=(-1)^{j-i}\binom{s}{j-i}, \ \ \ \ \ \binom{s}{k}=0\ \mathrm{for}\ k<0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the definition of matrix multiplication, written out.

$KQ$ is a column vector, hence $(KQ)^TKQ$ is the sum of squares of its components.

The $i$-th component ($0\leqslant i\leqslant n-s$) of $KQ$, by the definition, is equal to $$\require{cancel}\sum_{j=0}^{n}K_{ij}q_j=\sum_{j=\cancel{0}\color{red}{i}}^{n}(-1)^{j-i}\binom{s}{j-i}q_j\underset{j=i+k}{=}\sum_{k=0}^{\cancel{n-i}\color{red}{s}}(-1)^k\binom{s}{k}q_{i+k}=\Delta^s q_i$$ because $n-i\geqslant s$ [and $\binom{s}{k}=0$ when $k>s$].